# Simple queue system with scheduling support

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq, task-queue, queue-classic

I would need a queue system with scheduling support for a Ruby on Rails application. This is scheduling a job to be run at a certain time. Also it could be modified to be run sooner or later, or removed from the queue.

I'm thinking of using Sidekiq, but as I'm using a PostgreSQL database I was looking at queue_classic, but it seems not to have scheduling support.

Which one is a simple system that can handle timers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend sidekiq. It uses the mulithreading Actor Framework Celluloid and runs several background Jobs concurrently. It is not an Option if you want a sequentinal execution order of enqueued jobs

Comment: And anyway you should be also using some process monitoring daemon like monit. We actually do also experience delay job crashes but it's just getting restarted by monit

Comment: What about the overhead of having Delayed_Job + monit, or just Sidekiq?

Comment: Would use monit with sidekiq either. So not much overhead.

Comment: I would monit everything necessary. It's much more stable than god by the way.  And for the overhead of sidekiq - sooner or later you will be thinking about a memcache solution anyway. Lucky you've already setup redis - one of the best one available

Answer (score 0):

Check out delayed job, it enables both queuing and scheduling

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

Example

```
# with delayed_job running at a specific time
Notifier.delay(run_at: 5.minutes.from_now).signup(@user)
```

You could also take a look at https://github.com/javan/whenever for setting up cron jobs.

There is also a railscasts episodes for each of these gems (requires a subscription):
http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby-revised
http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby-revised

Comment: I have used Delayed_Job + whenever for a big project and I ran into issues with tasks not being executed. Simply restarting Delayed_Job fixed the problem, but it happened many times, so it's not reliable for me. Check their Github issues page, at this moment they have almost 200 open issues!

Comment: Which is abolutely normal for an active project